# avoid busy waiting and mode switches between realtime and non realtime threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, real-time

I have the following problem:
we do have a controller implemented with ros_control that runs on a Real Time, Xenomai linux-patched system. The control loop is executed by iteratively calling an update function. I need to communicate some of the internal state of the controller, and for this task I'm using LCM, developed in MIT. Regardless of the internal behaviour of LCM, the publication method is breaking the real time, therefore I've implemented in C++11 a publication loop running on a separated thread. But the loop it is gonna publish at infinite frequency if I don't synchronize the secondary thread with the controller. Therefore I'm using also condition variables.

Here's an example for the controller:

```
MyClass mc;

// This is called just once
void init(){
    mc.init();
}

// Control loop function (e.g., called every 5 ms in RT)
void update(const ros::Time& time, const ros::Duration& period) {
    double value = time.toSec();
    mc.setValue(value);
}
```

And for the class which is trying to publish:

```
double myvalue;
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cond;
bool go = true;

void MyClass::init(){
    std::thread thread(&MyClass::body, this);
}


void MyClass::setValue(double value){
    myvalue = value;
    {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
    go = true;
    }
    cond.notify_one();
} 

void MyClass::body() {
    while(true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex>lk(mutex);
        cond.wait(lk, [this] {return go;});    
        publish(myvalue); // the dangerous call
        go = false;
        lk.unlock();
    }
 }
```

This code produces mode switches (i.e., is breaking real time). Probably because of the lock on the condition variable, which I use to synchronize the secondary thread with the main controller and is in contention with the thread. If I do something like this:

```
void MyClass::body() {
    while(true) {
        if(go){
        publish(myvalue);
        go = false;            
        }

    }
 }
 void MyClass::setValue(double value){
    myvalue = value;
    go = true;        
}
```

I would not produce mode switches, but also it would be unsafe and most of all I would have busy waiting for the secondary thread.

Is there a way to have non-blocking synch between main thread and secondary thread (i.e., having `body` doing something only when `setValue` is called) which is also non-busy waiting?

Answer (score 0):

Use a lock free data structure.

In your case here you don't even need a data structure, just use an atomic for `go`. No locks necessary. You might look into using a semaphore instead of a condition variable to avoid the now-unused lock too. And if you need a semaphore to avoid using a lock you're going to end up using your base OS semaphores, not C++11 since C++11 doesn't even have them.

Comment: The atomic boolean for go would solve the unsafe loop, but not the busy waiting. According to [this site](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/locks-mutexes-semaphores.html) there's no efficient implementation of a semaphore in C++. A custom implementation would require again mutexes and condition variables.
What about `try_lock_until()` instead?
I could try the lock with a high timeout inside the secondary thread, and since nobody is using the mutex other than these two threads, the secondary thread would wake up only on the primary thread command, and not vice versa.
Am I right?

Comment: @MarcoCamurri: I did mention that you'd have to use your OS primitives instead of C++ to get a semaphore. The problem with using a mutex at all even with a timeout is that the real-time OS probably has RT priority tricks attached to all of the locking.

Comment: @MarcoCamurri: And in case I misunderstood your question, I hope that you are not having your high priority RT threads *waiting* on *anything* from low priority threads. High priority has to push and forget. Never wait except on your inputs, usually hardware.

Comment: I think this is what actually happens. The mode switch occurs, I think, because the primary thread, which is RT, is waiting to acquire the lock to access the condition variable to notify the secondary thread.

I decided to use `std::atomic_bool go`  and forget about the busy waiting. If the variable is not true, the while loop just continues without publishing.

Comment: I decided to use `std::atomic_bool go`  and forget about the busy waiting. If the variable is not true, the while loop just continues without publishing.

If you know a way with semaphore to put the secondary thread asleep without having the primary to wait whatsoever, I would really appreciate a code example. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Xenomai patched kernel.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't perfect, but it should reduce your busy-wait frequency with only occasional loss of responsiveness.

The idea is to use a naked condition variable wake up while passing a message through an atomic.

```
template<class T>
struct non_blocking_poke {
  std::atomic<T> message;
  std::atomic<bool> active;
  std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable v;

  void poke(T t) {
    message = t;
    active = true;
    v.notify_one();
  }
  template<class Rep, class Period>
  T wait_for_poke(const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>& busy_time) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(m);
    while( !v.wait_for(l, busy_time, [&]{ return active; } ))
    {}
    active = false;
    return message;
  }
};
```

The waiting thread wakes up every `busy_time` to see if it missed a message.  However, it will *usually* get a message faster than that (there is a race condition where it misses a message).  In addition, multiple messages can be sent without the reliever getting them.  However, if a message is sent, within about 1 second the receiver will get that message *or a later message*.

```
non_blocking_poke<double> poker;

// in realtime thread:
poker.poke(3.14);

// in non-realtime thread:
while(true) {
  using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
  double d = poker.wait_for_poke( 1s );
  std::cout << d << '\n';
}
```

In an industrial quality solution, you'll also want an abort flag or message to stop the loops.

Comment: I was actually trying with the xenomai pipes. The RT process writes a byte on the pipe, and the NRT one read from it. Reading from a pipe is blocking for the listener. But I have troubles, see [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350295/xenomai-xddp-with-stdthread).